# Is there a way to ensure no implicit culture settings are used?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have some classes which can't make assumptions about de used culture. These classes should always use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. However, I can't set the thread's current culture to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, because other classes rely on `<globalization culture="auto"`.

Is there a way to ensure some classes always use explicit culture method calls (like: `Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`) instead of assumed culture (like: `Convert.ToDecimal(value)`).

Maybe my question it's not 100% clear: I'd like to detect all methods which have an overload which uses CultureInfo, but also one without the CultureInfo which uses the CurrentCulture.

This includes implicit casts of numbers to string:

```
decimal value = 1.0;
string displayThis = string.Format("Costs: {0}", value);
```

The goal is to make sure some classes/methods don't assume anything about CultureInfo.

Supposedly I should solve this with FxCop. Any tips on this?

Comment: Perhaps you could create custom FxCop rules.

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal is not the problem. All the other methods (indirectly) using some CultureInfo-class are the problem. And FxCop or CodeAnalysis might be the solution...

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could easily roll your own `ConertInvariant.ToDecimal(...)` wrappers.

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal is not the problem

Comment: @doek, Feel free to replace it with another example. But I think ToDecimal also depends on the default CI.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Convert.ToDecimal Method (Object, IFormatProvider)` and pass your culture specific provider